# Send JSON from client to flask

Tags: ajax, flask

I'm trying to send a JSON from client side to Flask server, but keep getting 500 for my POST request.

client side:

```
var player_data = {};
player_data[$('#username').val()] = starting_money;

$('#play').on('click', function(){
//$.post("{{url_for('home')}}", {'data':starting_money});
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : "{{url_for('home')}}",
    contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    data : {'data':player_data}
});
```

Flask code:

```
@app.route("/home", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == "POST":
        player_data = request.json["data"]
        return redirect(url_for('main'))
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template("home.html")
```

Comment: but the initial GET request works to load the template?

Answer (score 0):

if this is all of your code, the 500 is because your imports. or you dont have a main view, and you need to `JSON.stringify( {'data':player_data})` before you post the data